# How do I create multiple markers and custom info boxes using the goMaps plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using the [goMap jQuery plugin](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/examples.php) to display markers on a map. What I want to do is similar to [this](http://www.nisw.co.uk/Long-Term-Conditions/Map.aspx), but using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3.

How do I add a custom box like in the example above?
How can I hide and show markers based on country?

I'm using code like this to createMarkers.

```
$.goMap.createMarker({latitude: 48.948813, longitude: 15.704004, id: 'm2'});
```

What I want to do is to add another property, i.e., country.  Any ideas how to acheive this with the goMaps plugin?

Is the goMaps plugin the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In new version goMap 1.3.0 you can use function showHideMarkerByGroup() to display or hide markers by group.
example: http://pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/solutions/group.html

Answer (score 1):

You also can try to use gmap3.

Try the examples on [gmap3.net](http://gmap3.net/examples.html)